# Handling Json response in Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#domain-checker').bind('submit',function(event){
        $.post('https://www.my-site.com/come/domainchecker.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(json) {
            if(json.error) {
                $(".rezultat").text(json.error.message).fadeIn();
            } else if(json.result) {

                $(".rezultat").text("Domen je dostupan").fadeIn();
            } else {

                $(".rezultat").text("Domen je zauzet").fadeIn();
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

This is response from my php script:

Domain is unavailable:

```
{
    "request":{
        "operation":"checkRegisterAvailability",
        "ip":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
    },
    "reply":{
       "code":"300",
       "detail":"success",
       "unavailable":{"domain":"google.com"}
    }
}
```

Domain is available:

```
{
   "request":{
       "operation":"checkRegisterAvailability",
       "ip":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
    },
    "reply":{
        "code":"300",
        "detail":"success",
        "available":{"domain":"johnsmithisthebest.com"}
    }
 }
```

When it's invalid:

```
{
     "request":{
         "operation":"checkRegisterAvailability",
         "ip":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
     },
     "reply":{
         "code":"300",
         "detail":"success",
         "invalid":{"domain":"asdasd.com.com"}
     }
}
```

I want to display different message for each of these responses with something like `$(".rezultat").text("Domen je dostupan").fadeIn()` 
I searched on internet about variables, values, json and jquery nothing helpful really.
The most helpful article i came up with is this one: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ 
But because this is my first jquery attempt i am writing here. I do not know where to search.

Follow up to Jamiecs answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#domain-checker').bind('submit',function(event){
        $.post('https://www.my-site.com/come/domainchecker.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        function(json) {
            if(json.reply.invalid) {
    $(".rezultat").text("Domen " + json.reply.invalid.domain + " nije validan").fadeIn();
            } else if(json.reply.unavailable) {

                $(".rezultat").text("Domen nije dostupan").fadeIn();
            } else {

                $(".rezultat").text("Domen je dostupan").fadeIn();
            }
        }, 'json');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

not printing anything.

**EDIT:**

I have added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

To domainchecker.php and it's working now.

Comment: How does the `HTML` code for `rezultat` look like?

Comment: `<div class="rezultat"></div>`
That is not problem that is working code i know for sure, my question is how do i determine which answer is passed through json in jquery.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, if I understand you correctly, but can't you check this way: `if(json.reply.unavailable != null) { $(".rezultat").text("Domen je dostupan").fadeIn(); }`?

Comment: Can I? I am asking here cuz I'm just starting with jquery coding :D

Comment: respectively `if(json.reply.available!= null) { $(".rezultat").text("Domen je zauzet").fadeIn(); }`

Comment: For your reference, meaning of `Domen je zauzet` is `Domain is unavailable` and `Domen je dostupan` means `Domain is available`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you layout your responses so they are easier to read (see question update) its clear that neither `json.error` nor `json.result` are ever in one of the three types or response. Also, `json.error.message` is never in any result... so the rest of this answer is a bit of a guess.

To determine if an "invalid" response came back you could do this:

```
if(json.reply.invalid){
    $(".rezultat").text("The domain " + json.reply.invalid.domain + " is invalid").fadeIn();
}
```

Similarly for an "unavailable" response

```
else if(json.reply.unavailable) {
    $(".rezultat").text("Domain is unavailable").fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: It's not printing any of these responses. See my edit

Comment: I tried using alert, code  is definitely not working. Also I try adding json.request.reply.invalid because reply is contained in request, but no luck. Help?

Comment: @Darktwen do you have any errors in the console. If you watch the network tab of your browser do you see the ajax request being made? Can you see a response or does the call error.

Comment: Of course, i always check network tab in inspect element, i get responses and everything. It sends post request and get response.

Comment: ....aaand what does the response look like? what about `console.log(json)` as the first line of your callback? (This is basic debugging stuff now!)

Comment: This si response from network tab `{"request":{"operation":"checkRegisterAvailability","ip":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"},"reply":{"code":"300","detail":"success","unavailable":{"domain":"google.com"}}}`
Oh my... I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ` to my domainchecker.php I made and It's working now, i didn't bothered to look at console tab sorry. Its working

Comment: One TINY questoin? How do i change color of text response using same div as now?
I know to add class to div with jquery but then if user checks domain several times it's just going to add more classes... Any solutions for this?

Comment: @Darktwen remove all the classes before adding a new one.